# Flutter can't find Google Playstore on real device with Android 11

Tags: android, flutter

I'm trying to implement [`google_sign_in`](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) in my flutter project but can't make it work because of this error

```
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 1153): Google Play Store is missing.
W/DynamiteModule( 1153): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.auth.api.fallback not found.
```

Google Playstore was installed by default and device are not rooted. [image: Screenshot of Google Playstore]. This never happen before with Android 10. Is there any way to fix this?

```
My Device:

Xiaomi Redmi Note 7 (Lavender)
Corvus OS 15.0 (RavenClaw/Android 11)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by flashing [GApps (NikGApps: Basic)](https://nikgapps.com/) over the stock that is installed by default. No need to wipe cache/dalvik. Just install and reboot. It works just fine now. Since the solution is not code/programming related, please refer to [their XDA thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/arm64-gapps-android-11-nikgapps-1st-may-2021.3915866/) for installation procedure.

Can't use OpenGapps because there is no support for Android 11 yet at this time.

**EDIT**

**This method is risky** and **could possibly brick your phone** so I would recommend installing an emulator with GApps on it and start debugging/developing the app in there instead of tweaking your phone directly.